# How to use an alternate font in acm-small

Tags: fontspec, acm

I am writing a paper in English and I am using standards of acm-small latex version to generate files. I have used the acmsmall-sample.tex which has been provided by default and edited it to generate my pdf.

However, now I want to use a few Hindi language words in my document. I learnt that this could be done using the `fontspec` package and XeLatex where I could set a new font family using `\newfontfamily`. But the problem is that, as soon as I use the `fontspec` package and `\newfontfamily` to set a font of Hindi and compile the .tex file, the English words' font-style changes (the words are now in a lighter font) in the .pdf obtained.

If anybody could advice me on any fix or workaround on this issue, it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is *no* real way to change fonts in `acm-small`. They are hardcoded in the class.

Answer (score 1):

`fontspec` loads the Latin Modern font instead of the classic Computer Modern. To get it back try

```
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss}
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}
```

However it is possible that the `OT1` font encoding is not compatible with your Hindi font.

Comment: The above changes threw error at the line which contained \maketitle. The error was "Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding OT1".

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really compile `acmsmall` documents with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`. If you have just a few words, you can do as follows.

### Prepare a file containing the words

Type in a document called `hindiwords.tex`

```
\documentclass[multi=varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Devanagari MT} % choose the one you prefer

\begin{document}

\begin{varwidth}{20cm}% sun
\strut
रवि
\end{varwidth}

\begin{varwidth}{20cm}% moon
\strut
चांद
\end{varwidth}

\begin{varwidth}{20cm}% earth
\strut
पृथ्वी
\end{varwidth}

\end{document}
```

Now we know what page the word corresponds to (a few words can be managed easily.

### Compile the word file

```
xelatex hindiwords.tex
```

### Prepare the document for the `acmsmall` class

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtecs]{acmsmall}

\usepackage{graphicx}

% set up the number correspondences
\newcommand\hindiwordsun{1}
\newcommand\hindiwordmoon{2}
\newcommand\hindiwordearth{3}

% the command for using them
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hindiword}[1]{%
  \raisebox{-\dp\strutbox}{%
    \includegraphics[page=\csname hindiword#1\endcsname]{hindiwords}%
  }%
}


% Metadata Information
\acmVolume{9}
\acmNumber{4}
\acmArticle{39}
\acmYear{2010}
\acmMonth{3}

% Copyright
\setcopyright{rightsretained}

% DOI
\doi{0000001.0000001}

%ISSN
\issn{1234-56789}

% Document starts
\begin{document}

% Page heads
\markboth{A. Uthor}{About inserting Hindi words in ACM documents}

% Title portion
\title{About inserting Hindi words in ACM documents}
\author{A. Uthor
\affil{\TeX.Stackexchange}}

\begin{abstract}
I want to use Hindi words in ACM class documents.
\end{abstract}

%
% The code below should be generated by the tool at
% http://dl.acm.org/ccs.cfm
% Please copy and paste the code instead of the example below. 
%
\begin{CCSXML}
<ccs2012>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010562</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Embedded systems</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>500</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010575.10010755</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Redundancy</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>300</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10010520.10010553.10010554</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Computer systems organization~Robotics</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
 <concept>
  <concept_id>10003033.10003083.10003095</concept_id>
  <concept_desc>Networks~Network reliability</concept_desc>
  <concept_significance>100</concept_significance>
 </concept>
</ccs2012>  
\end{CCSXML}

\ccsdesc[500]{Computer systems organization~Embedded systems}
\ccsdesc[300]{Computer systems organization~Redundancy}
\ccsdesc{Computer systems organization~Robotics}
\ccsdesc[100]{Networks~Network reliability}

%
% End generated code
%

\terms{Design, Algorithms, Performance}

\keywords{Wireless sensor networks, media access control,
multi-channel, radio interference, time synchronization}

\acmformat{A. Uthor, 2016. About inserting Hindi words in ACM documents}

\begin{bottomstuff}
This work is supported by the National Science Foundation, under
grant CNS-0435060, grant CCR-0325197 and grant EN-CS-0329609.

Author's addresses: A. Uthor, \TeX.Stackexchange
\end{bottomstuff}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}

The word for sun is \hindiword{sun}; the word for moon is \hindiword{moon}
and the word for earth is \hindiword{earth}

% History dates
\received{October 2016}{September 2016}{June 2016}

\end{document}
```

(I modified the `sample1.tex` file.)

### Process the main document

After running LaTeX (in the normal way), you will get

[image]

Higher resolution

[image]